# Checkboxlist and writing data to crm

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, crm, checkboxlist

```
    public partial class login_activity_survey : PageHelperBase
{
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label LblAnketSoru;
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox TxtFreeText;
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList ChkSecimler;
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem LiSecim;
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList RdSecimler;
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal Literalim;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string AnketId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AnketId"].ToString();
        GenerateSurvey(AnketId, plc);
    }

    void GenerateSurvey(string AnketId, System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder plch)
    {
        var db = new Xrm.XrmDataContext(Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection.Parse(Utils.getXrmConnectionString(_PortalBrandHelper.BrandProxy.BrandDedicatedCrmOrgName)));

        var AnketSoru = from p in db.new_survey_questions
                        orderby p.new_rank
                        select new { p.new_survey_questionid, p.new_question_text, p.new_question_type, p.new_rank, p.new_min_enumerator, p.new_max_enumerator };


        HtmlTable tbl = new HtmlTable();
        tbl.CellPadding = 2;
        tbl.CellSpacing = 3;


        HtmlTableRow r = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell c = new HtmlTableCell();
        c.InnerHtml = "<h3>İMMİB</h3>";
        c.ColSpan = 2;
        c.Align = "center";
        r.Cells.Add(c);
        tbl.Border = 1;

        tbl.ID = "Survey_Inner";
        tbl.Rows.Add(r);
        c = new HtmlTableCell();
        r = new HtmlTableRow();
        c.ColSpan = 2;
        c.InnerHtml = "<h4>EĞİTİM DEĞERLENDİRME FORMU</h4>";
        c.Align = "center";
        r.Cells.Add(c);
        tbl.Rows.Add(r);
        foreach (var item in AnketSoru)
        {
            r = new HtmlTableRow();
            c = new HtmlTableCell();
            c.InnerHtml = item.new_question_text.ToString();
            r.Cells.Add(c);

            switch (item.new_question_type.ToString())
            {
                case "2": //FreeText
                    c = new HtmlTableCell();
                    TxtFreeText = new TextBox();
                    TxtFreeText.ID = "Txt_" + item.new_survey_questionid.ToString();
                    TxtFreeText.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                    TxtFreeText.Width = 300;
                    TxtFreeText.Height = 50;
                    TxtFreeText.EnableViewState = true;
                    c.Controls.Add(TxtFreeText);
                    break;

                case "3": //CheckBox
                    c.ColSpan = 2;

                    var choises = from c1 in db.new_survey_question_choices
                                  where c1.new_survey_questionid == item.new_survey_questionid
                                  select c1;

                    ChkSecimler = new CheckBoxList();
                    ChkSecimler.ID = "Chkl_" + item.new_survey_questionid.ToString();
                    ChkSecimler.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
                    ChkSecimler.RepeatColumns = 2;
                    ChkSecimler.Attributes.Add("class", "ChkCss");
                    foreach (var ck in choises)
                    {
                        LiSecim = new ListItem();
                        LiSecim.Text = ck.new_name;
                        ChkSecimler.Items.Add(LiSecim);
                    }

                    c.Controls.Add(ChkSecimler);
                    break;

                case "4": //Enumeration RadioButton
                    c = new HtmlTableCell();
                    RdSecimler = new RadioButtonList();
                    RdSecimler.ID = "Rdl_" + item.new_survey_questionid.ToString();
                    RdSecimler.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
                    RdSecimler.CellPadding = 2;
                    c.Align = "center";
                    RdSecimler.Attributes.Add("class", "TblCss");



                    for (int i = Convert.ToInt32(item.new_min_enumerator); i <= Convert.ToInt32(item.new_max_enumerator); i++)
                    {
                        LiSecim = new ListItem();
                        LiSecim.Text = i.ToString();
                        RdSecimler.Items.Add(LiSecim);

                    }
                    c.Controls.Add(RdSecimler);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }

            r.Cells.Add(c);

            tbl.Rows.Add(r);

        }

        plch.Controls.Add(tbl);

    }
```

and

```
void SaveAnswers(Guid ContactId, Guid ActivityAttendee, Guid QuestionId, string FreeTextCevap)
    {
        var db = new Xrm.XrmDataContext(Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection.Parse(Utils.getXrmConnectionString(_PortalBrandHelper.BrandProxy.BrandDedicatedCrmOrgName)));

        Xrm.new_survey_answer answer = new Xrm.new_survey_answer();

        answer.new_participantid = ContactId;
        answer.new_activity_attendeeid = ActivityAttendee;
        answer.new_survey_questionid = QuestionId;
        answer.new_answer_text = FreeTextCevap;

        try
        {
            db.AddTonew_survey_answers(answer);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }


    }
    void SaveAnswers(Guid ContactId, Guid ActivityAttendee, Guid QuestionId, int EnumarationCevap)
    {
        var db = new Xrm.XrmDataContext(Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection.Parse(Utils.getXrmConnectionString(_PortalBrandHelper.BrandProxy.BrandDedicatedCrmOrgName)));

        Xrm.new_survey_answer answer = new Xrm.new_survey_answer();

        answer.new_participantid = ContactId;
        answer.new_activity_attendeeid = ActivityAttendee;
        answer.new_survey_questionid = QuestionId;
        answer.new_answer_numeric_value = EnumarationCevap;

        try
        {
            db.AddTonew_survey_answers(answer);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }


    }
    void SaveAnswers(Guid ContactId, Guid ActivityAttendee, Guid QuestionId, Guid CheckboxCevap)
    {
        var db = new Xrm.XrmDataContext(Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection.Parse(Utils.getXrmConnectionString(_PortalBrandHelper.BrandProxy.BrandDedicatedCrmOrgName)));

        Xrm.new_survey_answer answer = new Xrm.new_survey_answer();

        answer.new_participantid = ContactId;
        answer.new_activity_attendeeid = ActivityAttendee;
        answer.new_survey_questionid = QuestionId;
        answer.new_survey_question_choiceid = CheckboxCevap;

        try
        {
            db.AddTonew_survey_answers(answer);
            db.SaveChanges()
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

and

```
protected void SurveySubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string AttendeeId = Request.QueryString.Get("atId") != null ? Request.QueryString.Get("atId").ToString() : string.Empty;

        Guid EgitimKatilimcisi = new Guid("9163DA6E-3E97-E011-8A8F-001517557A34");

        foreach (Control c in plc.Controls)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable Survey_Inner = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable)c.FindControl("Survey_Inner");
            foreach (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow r in Survey_Inner.Rows)
            {
                foreach (Control ctr in r.Cells)
                {
                    foreach (Control ct in ctr.Controls)
                    {
                        if (ct.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox")
                        {
                            string TextCevap = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)ct).Text;

                            string deger = ct.ID.ToString();

                            Guid QuestionId = new Guid(deger.Substring(4));

                            SaveAnswers(this._PortalUserHelper.UserProxy.ContactId, EgitimKatilimcisi, QuestionId, TextCevap);

                        }
                        else if (ct.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList")
                        {
                            int Enumaration = Convert.ToInt32(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList)ct).SelectedValue);
                            string deger = ct.ID.ToString();

                            Guid QuestionId = new Guid(deger.Substring(4));

                            SaveAnswers(this._PortalUserHelper.UserProxy.ContactId, EgitimKatilimcisi, QuestionId, Enumaration);
                        }
                        else if (ct.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList")
                        {
                            int Cevap = Convert.ToInt32(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList)ct).SelectedItem);

                            string deger = ct.ID.ToString();

                            Guid QuestionId = new Guid(deger.Substring(4));

                            SaveAnswers(this._PortalUserHelper.UserProxy.ContactId, EgitimKatilimcisi, QuestionId, Cevap);


                        }
```

I've problem with this second else if for checkboxlist the others (radiobutton and freetxt) are ok.

Line 250:                            else if (ct.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList")
Line 251:                            {
Line 252:                                int Cevap = Convert.ToInt32(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList)ct).SelectedItem);
Line 253:
Line 254:                                string deger = ct.ID.ToString();

Problem is on line 252

### Server Error in '/' Application.

'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' türündeki nesne 'System.IConvertible' türüne atılamadı. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' türündeki nesne 'System.IConvertible' türüne atılamadı.

---

I have a checkboxlist i want to take all the selected items and write into the crm. any help?

Comment: Please also post your markup.

Comment: Added More Code and removed markups that are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in line 252 is because you're passing a `ListItem` to the [Convert.ToInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/813w40de.aspx) method, which doesn't accept that type.

Try changing it to:

```
int Cevap = Convert.ToInt32(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList)ct).SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Alright I found something else 
"answer.new_survey_question_choiceid" needs to be Guid i guess so Cevap must be the Guid right? so how can i convert this to the guid
 "((System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList)ct).SelectedValue" ?